# Should I integrate a background task in an API?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, api-design

I'm creating an API, which should run in a Thread. Now I really don't know if I should integrate / provide a background task in my API. To make it threadsafe is not the problem.

There are a lot of possibilitys to do threading in Android (IntentServices, native Thread solutions, AsyncTask etc.). Now I feel if I integrate a background task, let's say an AsyncTask, the developer which uses the API will be very limited to use it. Because considering f.e. orientation changes, the developer should be able to react on it properly. And it should be his choice how to do the threading, that he can stick to his design.

How should I handle this to provide the best operability? Providing a task which can be used or ignored? Just make the API thread safe and let the developer implement the API in the background task of his choice?

Another reason why I'm asking is that most APIs in Android/Java don't provide a background task, but are threadsafe.

Is there a general rule about that?

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it all your API operations have to be synchronous with the exception of heavy load ones, like networking or file reading, which should provide an asynchronous-capable method that requires a callback. You also have to provide the interface that needs to be implemented for your API async callbacks.

If the API consists of a bus or server-style method waiting and polling for user input then the API itself must **not** run on the main thread. It should probably be built as either a Service or Asynctask. Do not forget to retain a reference to the main thread in a Handler to be able to update the IU.

And even if it's not of that type I'd build it in a background thread and internally use a Handler to make the calls.

Comment: I'm with you. To provide callbacks and make use of handlers for proper interacting isn't the problem. Consider the API includes a Service. Then it have to be registered in the manifest. That's a point which I would like to avoid. Even on orientation changes the API should be able to survive this event. IMO these are points which are best controlable without integrating a background task in an API.